# Pre-apply parameter to unityscript function and use that as an object to send into another function

Tags: unity-game-engine, arguments, parameter-passing, unityscript

I have one complex function. I planned to send a function into it.

```
function ComplexFunction( customFunction : function)
{
    //Complex things
    customFunction();
    //Complex things
}
```

But the function I planned to send has different signature

```
function FunctionA ( enumParameter : EnumX )
function FunctionB ( enumParameter : EnumY )
function FunctionC ( enumParameter : EnumZ )
```

So this is not an option because I don't know what type will be sending in.

```
function ComplexFunction( customFunction : function , enumForCustomFunction : Enum??? )
```

(This is Unity's unityscript with #pragma strict, so I must indicate the parameter type.)

So I think about pre-apply those enum parameter, make it into parameter-less function and send that in for `ComplexFunction` to call. Is this possible?

Comment: never worked with Unity3d, but couldn't you just wrap the real function to be called with an unnamed function? (e.g. `ComplexFunction(function () { return FunctionA(EnumX); });`)

Comment: did my reply answer your question? if yes, please accept.

Comment: Thanks for reminding! I was kind of very busy :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain JavaScript you can bind parameters to a function like this:

```
var multiply = function(x,y) { return x*y };
var doubleIt = multiply.bind(null, 2);
```

So calling `doubleIt(3)` now returns `6`. (The `null` sets the context of the function, in this case we don't care about that, so we use `null`). You can read more on this topic here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

---

In your case I would call `ComplexFunction` with `FunctionA` like so:

```
ComplexFunction(FunctionA.bind(null, AValueFromEnumX));
```

Comment: So this is what we called 'Partial application'? I read about it just now. :P

Comment: Yes, this is partial application. The function `doubleIt` is 'partially applied'. This is also called 'curried', if you know a little bit of Haskell (it's not exactly the same, but pretty much).